# Old versions of FIDE laws of chess?

Tags: rules, history, fide

Is it possible to view or obtain old versions of the FIDE Laws of Chess?  I would like to trace the history of when various rules were added or modified.

The FIDE handbook only goes back as far as the [2009-2014 rules](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E01pre2014) as far as I can see.